Difference between $PGL(2,\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and $GL(2,\mathbb{Q}_p)$ in terms of determinant
I'm trying to understand the difference between $PGL(2,\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and $GL(2,\mathbb{Q}_p)$ in terms of determinant.
For example, in the real case, $PGL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ up to scalar invertible matrices. Then, taking $A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ we can consider the representative $$diag(|det(A)|^{-1/2},|det(A)|^{-1/2})\cdot A$$ and get a matrix with determinant $\pm 1$.
Is there a similar way to understand $PGL(2,\mathbb{Q}_p)$?
For the real case I really used the fact that up to a sign, every real number has a square root.
This is not the case for $p$-adics to my understanding.
Follow up question - what about $PGL(n,\mathbb{Q}_p)$?
